# Calculate $I=\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{2z-1}$ by Residue's Theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Calculate $I=\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{2z-1}$ by Residue's Theorem.

We have $z=\frac{1}{2}$ is the simple pole of the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{2z-1} =\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{z-\frac{1}{2}}$

Applying the Residue's Theorem we get

$I=2 \pi i \textrm{ Res } (f;\frac{1}{2})= 2 \pi i \textrm{ lim }_{z \to \frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{2}= \pi i $

Is it true? Thank you so much.

Comment: It looks good to me as long as the contour $|z|=1$ is counter-clockwise.